# How to filter with "or" condition in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, filtering, spreadsheet

I am trying to create an array formula in Google Sheets that includes data from one column, but will also include a skipped cell if certain conditions are met.

The conditions are that the date on the referenced sheet matches the date selected (cell A2) & the type of item matches the type for that sheet ("IMPLEMENTS" == "Loaders"). But I also need it to skip a line (or include a blank line) if there are no "IMPLEMENTS" for that particular sequence number.

Here is the sheet that I am trying to get this to work on:
["loaders" sheet + formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXlto.png)

And the sheet that the formula references:
["data" sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afzZT.png)

My current formula is:
=FILTER( data!B2:B , data!D2:D="IMPLEMENT", data!A2:A = text(A2,"mm-dd-yy"))

But, as you can see in the first image, there is no line "21" because there is no "IMPLEMENT" for sequence #21 - but I still need a line 21 to be included, even if it's blank. Is there a way to do this?

**Edit**: Here is a link to a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U3QF9e_CfDBmiPUU31i6n7jTWO7G3OEliQ2jKicoADw/edit

Comment: You can make use of this [Blank Sheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to create an anonymous sheet. Fill it with test data + expected output (manually entered) & then share the sheet URL here for us to check it out.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea this existed! I edited the post with a link to the sample sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added formula to the [sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U3QF9e_CfDBmiPUU31i6n7jTWO7G3OEliQ2jKicoADw/edit#gid=1917700258). Please do test it out.

```
=let(Σ,indirect(text(D4,"m/d")&"!A3:I"),Λ,unique(tocol(index(Σ,,9),1)),
       reduce({"Mat.","Desc.","Prod.#","Seq."},sequence(counta(Λ)),lambda(a,c,{a;ifna(filter(choosecols(Σ,3,4,8,9),index(Σ,,5)=D3,index(Σ,,9)=index(Λ,c)),wraprows(,4,))})))
```

[image]

Comment: I put your formula into cell E5 of the "My Output" tab for testing. Then I changed the date in B2 - but the output did not update. I'm guessing I need to incorporate your formula into the one I already had, but I don't understand what you did well enough to figure out how to do that. Could you explain?